# Naming a Xming window and automatic kill

Tags: windows, bash, display, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xming

I am using xming in WSL for displaying output. When I run multiple bash terminal programs, the xming window does not kill automatically when script exits. Q1: How to kill on exit automatically? Also, the default xming window name is always the name of script(python in my case). Q2: Is it possible to change that display name so that I can track easily?

Comment: Answer depends on your settings before launching Xming. If you choose 'Multiple Window' then Xming window will be close as soon as you exit from that program. And what do you mean by display name?

Comment: @Biswapriyo display name is the name appearing on the top of the window. I do not remember setting up/ choosing 'multiple window'. Will check this.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of x11-apps. See all the window with different name. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSXy7.png